# Special groups and special linear groups

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-groups, p-groups

Is there a connection between a special group (i.e. a p-group with its derived group, center and frattini subgroup all equal) and the special linear group (i.e. group of matrices with determinant=1)? I've seen the first one in finite group theory and the other one in linear algebra so I'm not sure if there's something more to it or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably not. I suspect that "special" has several unrelated meanings in different contexts as is the case with many adjectives in mathematics (like "normal" and "regular").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really -- there are too few words available to assign a common term for all situations one would like to distinguish. So the defined term is not "special" but "special linear", respectively "special $p$-group".